# $type for Array field returns false

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongojs

```
I have a collection having following data:

{"_id" : ObjectId("5220222f8188d30ce85d61cc"),
```

"testfields" : [{
              "test_id" : 1,
              "test_name" : "xxxx"
          }]
    }

```
when I query :
db.testarray.find({ "testfields" : { "$type" : 4 } })

it returns no data,but same returns data when I do:
db.testarray.find({ "$where" : "Array.isArray(this.testfields)" })

It returns data, do the type:4 identifies some other kind of list?
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `testfields` is an `Array`, `$type : 4` will perform the "is array" check against every element in `testfields` as opposed to `testfields` itself.  Since your `testfields` contains just one `Object`, it does not get returned.

If on the other hand you inserted the following into your collection,

```
db.testarray.insert( { "testfields" : [ { "test_id" : 1, "test_name" : "xxxx" }, 
                                        [ "a", "b" ] ] } );
```

it would get returned because now one of the elements of `testfields` is an `Array`.

More info explaining this in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/#op._S_type).

Comment: thanx, but I want to check it only for the testfields. I cannot use $where, because it dosen't work with $match.